# Can I get prettier types out of Zod inferred types in my Typedoc documentation?

Tags: zod, typedoc

### My problem

I'm first using `z.infer` to produce types from Zod schemas and then Typedoc to generate documentation for those types, but the output is less than ideal in a few ways:

- The types come out as type aliases in the form `TypeName: z.infer<typeof schemaName>`, which isn't helpful in itself (thankfully `schemaName` is clickable)
- The schemas come out with all sorts of Zod types in the way, e.g. `ZodObject<{ name: ZodOptional<ZodString>}>` instead of the expected `{ name?: string }`
- Optional object properties in schemas come out as e.g. `name: undefined | string` rather than `name?: string` or even `(optional) name?: string`, which Typedoc does for regular (non-Zod) types.

### Example

Here's an example (from [repro repo](https://github.com/shawninder/zod-typedoc-ugly)):

**index.ts**

```
import z from 'zod'

export const userSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().optional()
})

export type ZodUser = z.infer<typeof userSchema>

export type TypescriptUser = {
  name?: string
}
```

Once I run Typedoc on this, it's fairly obvious that the results are better with TypescriptUser than with ZodUser:

#### ZodUser

**file:///…/zod-typedoc-ugly/docs/types/ZodUser.html**:

```
ZodUser: z.infer<typeof userSchema>
```

**file:///…/zod-typedoc-ugly/docs/variables/userSchema.html**:

```
userSchema: ZodObject<{
    name: ZodOptional<ZodString>;
}, "strip", ZodTypeAny, {
    name: undefined | string;
}, {
    name: undefined | string;
}> = ...
```

---

VS

---

#### TypescriptUser

**file:///…/zod-typedoc-ugly/docs/types/TypescriptUser.html**:

```
TypescriptUser: {
    name?: string;
}
```

### Seeking Solution

I'm looking for a way to get the advantages of Zod (I can use the schema responsible for the type at runtime to validate inputs) along with the simpler docs of zod-less Typescript types.
I understand I can maintain the two separately, but I would rather that be automatic and not introduce a risk for both of these versions to fall out of sync.

Is there a better way, a workaround or an alternative here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of approximately 5 minutes ago, yes. There is a way. [typedoc-plugin-zod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc-plugin-zod) can be used to make TypeDoc use the inferred type instead of the type node when converting the `z.infer` type aliases. It will also replace the original schema declaration's type to refer to the `ZodUser` type.

(obvious disclaimer, I just wrote this)

Comment: I like that it's already at v1.0.1 

Comment: @Cully I forgot to include the repo info so that npm would link to it 

Comment: Wow, this is already so much better! Is there anything that can be done about optional object properties so that they can show as e.g.`(optional) propName?: string` as opposed to `propName: undefined | string`?

Comment: P.S. Did you just whip this up in response to this question? So awesome, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @Shawn looks like that's a bug in TypeDoc itself, I'm having a rough time reproducing it without zod though... this isn't the first time I've seen someone ask for something like this, you were the impetus to get me to give it a shot though

Comment: Finally reduced to a minimal reproduction, might have time to look at it this weekend - https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/2200

Comment: ... or, ya know, it'll take 10 minutes to fix the bug once I finally get a useful reproduction. Fixed in TypeDoc 0.23.27

Comment: It's working perfectly on my end! Can't thank you enough.